# tuareg ocaml previous command

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I am a new to ocaml. couldn't install rlwrap since I use a school computer. 
So I have to stick to emacs tuareg.

My question is: 
How to bind an up arrow key to the previous command in tuareg?

Answer (score 4):

Just use M+p instead of the arraw key :) 
But you can also add the following lines to your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'tuareg-interactive-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (local-set-key (kbd "<up>") 'comint-previous-input)
 )
)
```